# How does ActiveMQ prevent starvation of low priority messages?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, priority-queue

I have implemented a priority queue in ActiveMQ. If the queue is being continuously flooded with the high priority messages, the low priority messages will never get processed. How does ActiveMQ handle such situations or how can this situation be avoided or handled?

Answer (score 4):

ActiveMQ doesn't attempt to do anything to prevent this as it's up to you to solve it based on the needs of your application.  If you have such a situation you might want to consider instead using a Queue per priority to allow for load balancing across the Queues.

Answer (score 1):

Extending to Tim Bish's answer, there are some features in ActiveMQ you can use to handle this situation.

You can setup a virtual destination to filter out high and low prio messages, like this (inside a virtualDestinationInterceptor tag).

```
<virtualDestinations>
  <compositeQueue name="ALL">
     <forwardTo>
          <filteredDestination selector="JMSPriority &lt; 5" queue="LOW.PRIO"/>
          <filteredDestination selector="JMSPriority &gt; 4" queue="HIGH.PRIO"/>
     </forwardTo>
  </compositeQueue>
</virtualDestinations>
```

Then you can follow the alternative strategy presented [here](http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-support-priority-queues.html).
You put one consumer on the LOW.PRIO queue and multiple consumers on the HIGH.PRIO queue. Then the LOW.PRIO messages will be handled, but with less threads than high prio messages.

You can also read messages directly from the "ALL" queues with said selectors in your consumer application.